# Why Maximum Frequency is showing high? in Task Manager

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, task-manager

I have created my secondary Domain Controller in Window server 2008 Standard R2.I have only install a Domain Controller role, that's it.

than ,why the maximum frequency is showing high? i.e around 89% and Cpu utilization is just showing 6% ( please see the print-screen )

I think because of High Maximum Frequency the vb script is running slow, which i have created for sending mail if some Critical error is generated in Event Viewer. I have scheduled this vb script via Task Scheduler ( Trigger = on an Critical error , Action = mail sending vb script )
[image]

Do you have any idea? why it is happening..

Thanks & Regards,
Param

Answer (score 6):

This is power saving (or similar actions) taking place - reducing the operating frequency of the CPU during low-load times to save power and reduce heat.

At 89%, this means the CPU is running at 89% of its advertised frequency - as soon as the load increases on your system again, this will probably rise back up closer to 100%. Try running a CPU-intensive task to see this in action.

If you're really concerned about the number, you can disable processor frequency scaling (I think that is what Windows calls it - don't quote me on that!).

Comment: This is a spot on anwser (Pretty much about to post the same) Also the processor will sometimes show 110% etc for a few seconds as they include burst speed in this calculation.

Answer (score 2):

My CPU is at maximum frequency all the time because I have not got intel speed-step enabled. This metric basically just tells you at what frequency your CPU is running, not what level of utilization there is. Are you worried about CPU frequencies to save power? If you are, please list details of all your hardware, if you're not bothered about power consumption then it is absolutely nothing to worry about.